# why is .grid giving me an error when I am trying to move my button

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext

win = tk.Tk()

win.title("My First Game")
win.configure(bg="black")
win.geometry("640x400")

label = tk.Label(win, text="test", fg="red", bg="black").pack()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(win, width=130, height=20)
canvas1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry(win, font="Helvetica 10")
canvas1.create_window(65, 10, window=entry1)
entry1.insert(0, "Type here")


def shortcut():
    Shortcut = tk.Label(win, fg="red", bg="black", text="test2")
    Shortcut.pack()


button1 = tk.Button(win, text="Enter", fg="red", bg="black", command=shortcut)
button1.pack()

exit_button = tk.Button(win, text="Quit", padx=4, pady=2, bg="black", fg="red", command=quit)
exit_button.pack()
exit_button.grid(row=0, column=2)


win.mainloop()
```

Why is this giving me an error? I tried in a separate project with just a black screen and the button and it worked fine. But when I put it in the code above it doesn't work

```
line 42, in <module> exit_button.grid(row=0, column=2)
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack
```

Comment: You haven't shown us the error...

Comment: Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve]. Have you done any debugging?

Comment: Right now the code isn't runnable. Please provide a minimal runnable example, or mre: [mre].

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: `pack()` and `grid()` are two different layout managers - when you use `grid()` then don't use `pack()`. You can't use both at the same time because both use different calculations to organize elements and it makes conflict.

Comment: @furas You can't use them under the same parent widget, otherwise it's actually recommended, and I do it all the time.

Comment: @10Rep I know it :) You could say it to OP. Maybe you could create anwser with example code which can explain it to OP - it seems OP add full code.

Comment: The error tells you exactly why. I recommend you search this site for that exact error. FWIW, in that error message "." represents the root window.

Comment: @furas I replaced the .pack with the .grid like this `exit_button = tk.Button(win, text="Quit", padx=4, pady=2, bg="black", fg="red", command=quit)
exit_button.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=tk.E)` and i get the same error

Comment: as @10Rep mentioned in comment for me - you can't use `pack` and `grid` in the same `Frame` but you use `pack()` to put other elements in the same frame/window. If you want to use `grid` then you may need put Frame (using `pack()`) and inside this frame you can put Button using `grid` - and should resolve problem with error - but it may not resolve problem with layout because it will create empty first column and this column will have widht `0` - better use `grid()` for all widgets in current frame/window

Comment: @EthanC I don't feel like posting an answer, but essentially what that means is you need to remove the line `exit_button.grid(...)` and everything will work fine.

Comment: @10Rep I finally figured it out. I didn't know what furas meant  by saying that pack() and grid() don't go together. I thought that just meant that you couldn't use both of them for the same button or something. Thx for clarifying it helps me out so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @10Rep mentioned in comment - you can remove `grid()` to resolve problem with error.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def shortcut():
    shortcut = tk.Label(win, text="test2")
    shortcut.pack()

# --- main ---

win = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(win, text="test")
label.pack()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(win) #, width=130, height=20)
canvas1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry(canvas1)
canvas1.create_window(0, 0, window=entry1, anchor='nw')
entry1.insert(0, "Type here")

button1 = tk.Button(win, text="Enter", command=shortcut)
button1.pack()

exit_button = tk.Button(win, text="Quit", command=win.destroy)
exit_button.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

But I expect that you used `grid()` to organize two buttons in one line.
Problem is that you can't mix `pack()` and `grid()` in one window/frame and I see two solutions:

First is to use only `grid()` to organize all widgets

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def shortcut():
    shortcut = tk.Label(win, text="test2")
    shortcut.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

# --- main ---

win = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(win, text="test")
label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(win) #, width=130, height=20)
canvas1.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

entry1 = tk.Entry(canvas1)
canvas1.create_window(0, 0, window=entry1, anchor='nw')
entry1.insert(0, "Type here")

button1 = tk.Button(win, text="Enter", command=shortcut)
button1.grid(row=2, column=0)

exit_button = tk.Button(win, text="Quit", command=win.destroy)
exit_button.grid(row=2, column=1)

win.mainloop()
```

Second is to put `Frame` (using `pack()`) and put buttons inside this frame using `grid()`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def shortcut():
    shortcut = tk.Label(win, text="test2")
    shortcut.pack()

# --- main ---

win = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(win, text="test")
label.pack()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(win) #, width=130, height=20)
canvas1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry(canvas1)
canvas1.create_window(0, 0, window=entry1, anchor='nw')
entry1.insert(0, "Type here")

# - frame with grid -

f = tk.Frame(win)
f.pack()

button1 = tk.Button(f, text="Enter", command=shortcut)
button1.grid(row=0, column=0)

exit_button = tk.Button(f, text="Quit", command=win.destroy)
exit_button.grid(row=0, column=1)

# -

win.mainloop()
```

or using `pack(side=...)`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def shortcut():
    shortcut = tk.Label(win, text="test2")
    shortcut.pack()

# --- main ---

win = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(win, text="test")
label.pack()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(win) #, width=130, height=20)
canvas1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry(canvas1)
canvas1.create_window(0, 0, window=entry1, anchor='nw')
entry1.insert(0, "Type here")

# - frame with pack(side=...) -

f = tk.Frame(win)
f.pack()

button1 = tk.Button(f, text="Enter", command=shortcut)
button1.pack(side='left')

exit_button = tk.Button(f, text="Quit", command=win.destroy)
exit_button.pack(side='left')

# -

win.mainloop()
```